# LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8" not more working since March

Tags: linux, bash

On German Linux-system I run script to grep information by date from English document.

```
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8" grep -a "\[$(date -d "yesterday" +%b\ %d)" file.log
```

Since March script don't grep information anymore. Before it worked fine over months.

Manual I see the problem, that not "Mar" but German "Mär" is in search string:

```
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8" echo $(date -d "yesterday" +%b\ %d)
Mär 27
```

Following `LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8"` is not more working correct.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `LC_TIME` **for grep** and **for echo** not for `date`.

```
echo $(LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8" date -d "yesterday" +%b\ %d)
grep -a "[$(LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8" date -d "yesterday" +%b\ %d)"
```

Comment: but what to change here that it works?

LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8" grep -a "\[$(date -d "yesterday" +%b\ %d)" file.log

Comment: the same change `anything anything $(LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8" date ...) anything anything`

Comment: okay, now I got it ;)

Many thanks!